# Sql_ How to insert ordered data

Tags: sql

I am using SQL server 2012, I have following table:

```
ProId   Debit Credit Date                   TrId    BatchNo
Pro_1   NULL    2   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 SId_23  NULL
Pro_1   NULL    2   2014-08-15 14:37:13.000 SId_33  NULL
Pro_1   NULL    2   2014-08-15 14:37:15.000 SId_33  NULL
Pro_1   NULL    2   2014-08-15 14:37:34.000 SId_33  NULL
Pro_1   NULL    2   2014-08-15 14:37:26.000 SId_33  NULL
```

When I fetch data from it, I use 'order by Date' clause, but I want to order each record when it is inserted in the table, is there any way to perform this?

Comment: But isn't the date be considered for this? Note : I did not down vote this.

Comment: What's the purpose of inserting in any order? when fetching the data, you only need to order it again! anyway, if you want it in a particular order, you only have to insert in the required order.

Comment: i wanted to get balance on inserting each record but now i have changed my plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the primary key of this table. If you have one let sat `Id int` you can use that as your order by column.

```
Select *
From TableName
Order By Id
```

Otherwise, you can add additional column to table `CreatedOn Datetime` and insert `GETDATE()` as value

i.e

```
Insert Into TableName (Col1,Col2,CreatedOn)
Values (Val1,Val2,GETDATE())
```

Then

```
Select *
From TableName
Order By CreatedOn
```

Comment: the same thing m using at the moment humpty dumpty

Comment: @Khan: So what is the issue then?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what order you insert the data in. You cannot guarantee the order of data returned from the table unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT`